# Countif like function in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am looking for a way of counting the number of times a value in a field appears in a range of fields in a csv file much the same as countif in excel although I would like to use an awk command if possible.

So column 1 whould have the range of values and column 2 would have the times the value appears in column 1

Comment: You should add an example to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count how many times each value appears in the first column and append the count to the end of each line:

```
$ cat file
1,2,3
1,2,3
9,7,4
1,5,7
3,2,1

$ awk -F, '{c[$1]++;l[NR]=$0}END{for(i=0;i++<NR;){split(l[i],s,",");print l[i]","c[s[1]]}}' file
1,2,3,3
1,2,3,3
9,7,4,1
1,5,7,3
3,2,1,1
```

Comment: what is the c and l here? `c[$1]++;l[NR]`

Answer (score 0):

One more solution using Perl.

```
perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}++;$kl{$.}=$_;END {for(sort keys %kl) { $x=(split(",",$kl{$_}))[0]; print "$kl{$_},$kv{$x}" }} '
```

Borrowing input from Chris

```
$ cat kbiles.txt
1,2,3
1,2,3
9,7,4
1,5,7
3,2,1

$ perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}++;$kl{$.}=$_;END {for(sort keys %kl) { $x=(split(",",$kl{$_}))[0]; print "$kl{$_},$kv{$x}" }} ' kbiles.txt
1,2,3,3
1,2,3,3
9,7,4,1
1,5,7,3
3,2,1,1

$
```