# Countif like function in AWK with field headers

Tags: awk

I am looking for a way of counting the number of times a value in a field appears in a range of fields in a csv file much the same as countif in excel although I would like to use an awk command if possible.

So column 6 should have the range of values and column 7 would have the times the value appears in column 7, as per below

```
>awk -F, '{print $0}' file3
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ

>awk -F, '{print $6}' file3
test
SBCD
AWER
ASDF
ASDQ
ASDQ
```

What i want is:

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test,count
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD,1
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER,1
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF,1
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ,2
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ,2
```

#adds field name count that I want:

```
 awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ print $0, "count"}
 NR>1{ print $0}' file3
```

Ho do I get the output I want?

I have tried this from previous/similar question but no joy,

```
>awk -F, 'NR>1{c[$6]++;l[NR>1]=$0}END{for(i=0;i++<NR;){split(l[i],s,",");print l[i]","c[s[1]]}}' file3
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ,
,
,
,
,
,
```

very similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530996/countif-like-function-in-awk)
similar python related [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905807/countif-function-in-python), for my ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{print $0,"count";next}FNR==NR{arr[$6]+=1;next}FNR>1{print $0,arr[$6]}' file.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test,count
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD,1
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER,1
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF,1
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ,2
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ,2
```

Explanation: this is two-pass approach, hence `file.txt` appears twice. I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`), then for first line (header) I `print` it followed by `count` and instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line, so nothing other is done regarding 1st line, then for first pass, i.e. where global number of line (`NR`) is equal to number of line in file (`FNR`) I count number of occurences of values in 6th field and store them as values in array `arr`, then instruct GNU `AWK` to get to `next` line, so onthing other is done in this pass. During second pass for all lines after 1st (`FNR>1`) I `print` whole line (`$0`) followed by corresponding value from array `arr`

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: tks, that works

Answer (score 1):

You did not copy the code from the linked question properly. Why change `l[NR]` to `l[NR>1]` at all? On the other hand, you should change `s[1]` to `s[6]` since it's the sixth field that has the key you're counting:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{c[$6]++;l[NR]=$0}END{for(i=0;i++<NR;){split(l[i],s,",");print l[i]","c[s[6]]}}'
```

You can also output the header with the new field name:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR==1{print $0,"count"}NR>1{c[$6]++;l[NR]=$0}END{for(i=0;i++<NR;){split(l[i],s,",");print l[i],c[s[6]]}}'
```

Comment: I am not geting exact output I want with these 2 commands

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                        # define input/output field delimiters as comma
      { lines[NR]=$0
        if (NR==1) next
        col6[NR]=$6                         # copy field 6 so we do not have to parse the contents of lines[] in the END block
        cnt[$6]++
      }
END   { for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
            print lines[i], (i==1 ? "count" : cnt[col6[i]] )
      }
' file3
```

This generates:

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test,count
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD,1
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER,1
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF,1
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ,2
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQF,row4_5,ASDQ,2
```

Comment: tks, that works